Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1.1' to data type int
I have two columns, one of data type Smallint and the other int. I am trying to concatenate the two columns and a '.' to produce one final value but I keep getting the error:

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1.1' to data type
int

For instance, if I have '1' in ColumnA and a '1' in ColumnB, I want to concatenate them like CONCAT(ColumnA, '.', ColumnB) to give me the value '1.1'.
This is my code:
CAST(CASE 
         WHEN ColumnA IS NOT NULL AND (ColumnB = 0 OR ColumnB IS NULL) 
             THEN ColumnA
         WHEN ColumnA IS NOT NULL AND ColumnB IS NOT NULL AND ColumnB > 0 
             THEN CONCAT(ColumnA, '.', ColumnB) 
     END AS NUMERIC(2, 1)) AS 'VERSION'

I have tried all different variations of a CAST, but nothing seems to be working. Any help would be much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

This fiddle demonstrates the error https://dbfiddle.uk/bFGfqAPi

Which dbms are you using? (The accepted answer is product specific.)

ColumnA is a SMALLINT in the first case so all following cases must also be convertable to INT. If we Cast the first case into a VARCHAR then all following cases can be VARCHAR. CONCAT produces a VARCHAR.
 SELECT *, CAST(
                CASE WHEN ColumnA IS NOT NULL AND (ColumnB = 0 OR ColumnB IS NULL) THEN CAST(ColumnA as Varchar(10))
                     WHEN ColumnA IS NOT NULL AND ColumnB IS NOT NULL AND ColumnB > 0 THEN CONCAT(ColumnA, '.', ColumnB) 
                END 
                AS NUMERIC(2,1)
               ) AS 'VERSION'
FROM Example

fiddle



ColumnA
ColumnB
VERSION




1
1
1.1


2
2
2.2


3
4
3.4




Ha! You, sir, are a lifesaver. That's exactly what I was after and it's worked brilliantly. Thank you so much @Bart

You can run any calculation within SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY call to see what datatype it limits your other cases to.  https://dbfiddle.uk/bfKFehLI

https://dbfiddle.uk/61RhlTrl It's not the first case that decides, it's dependent on data type precedence across all WHEN expressions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
